# Install Tiger/Leopard/Snow Leopard on multiple partitions

Tags: macos, mac, multi-boot

I have a mac I want to partition so I can have three versions of OS X to choose to boot into. Before I go try stuff, I wanted to check if someone has done it or knows a handy way to do this which works?
Thanks!

Comment: Remember that the minimum version of OS X you can run is the version your Mac came with. So if it came with Leopard, you won't be able to run Tiger on it. But if you can do this, I'd be interested to know how well it works. :)

Comment: If the OS runs on both PPC & Intel why couldn't you install an older OS on a newer laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible - just use disk utility for partitioning. Be sure to backup your files on the hd you going to use this 3x OS X setup.

I'd recommend moving your home folder to an second drive, so you have your user data on all systems plus a speed boost because the head (OS X) can now work parallel with the legs and arms (user data).

1) on the 2nd disk (must be an internal disk) and make a new folder and name it after your current user folder f.eg. "patte"
2) copy all the content from the old into the new user folder - don’t change anything while copying or you could end up missing some files
3) go into the system preferences and right click on your user, there's an advanced menu were you can choose the new location of your user folder. After that you ought to restart your computer. If everything worked you should now see the house icon on the new user folder and an generic icon on the old user folder. Feel free to delete the old one.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with Leopard and Snow Leopard, it worked great. I had Leopard, wanted to try Snow Leopard before upgrading. So I installed SL on a new partition (I had a spare drive, didn't repartition my main drive for this, on a Mac Pro).

It all worked very well... Nothing unexpected. You just select the partition you want to install on, and let it do its thing. Then you can boot on either partition...

What surprised me though (I'm relatively new to the Mac...) is that I could run applications from my Leopard drive directly under Snow Leopard... I didn't have to re-install programs like Firefox etc. Spotlight in the fresh new SL would find my documents and apps just like that on the original Leopard partition. It went so smoothly that I just rebooted and upgraded to SL.

I didn't find any problems in doing so. Removing the test SL partition also was uneventful, I just deleted the partition in Disk Utility, and it disappeared from the Settings -> Startup Disk control panel...

So I'd say go ahead, have a blast :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll find [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) very useful for this -- it will present you with an OS selection screen upon every boot.